# Is it possible to create a custom event variable and pass it through click()?

Tags: javascript

Currently have a game I am working on.

When you manually click on a specific object, particles fly out where you click it by using the `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`.

I am implementing a feature where you can create "workers" and set them at specific x,y coordinates that'll click every couple of seconds.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
let el = document.elementFromPoint( x, y )
el.click()
```

But the downside to this is that it doesnt have an event attached to it containing the `x`, and `y` coordinates like a normal click event has. Is there a way to pass it along?

EDIT:

So lets say whenever you click on `div.square`, particles come out.

I have a click event listener on `div.square` that looks something like this:

```
square.onclick = ( event ) => {
  create_particles( event )
}
```

If I were to simulate a click by doing `click()`, `square.onclick` will fire but the `event` parameter would be empty. Is there a way to pass along those coordinates somehow?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events

Comment: @epascarello Hmm... I can create the event but how would I pass it through the `click()`? I edited the question to give more details.

Comment: Did you not look at the code? It is all there.... `dispatchEvent`

Comment: @epascarello Oops. Re-read it and got it working. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create an event object, populate it with the nessisary values for `clientX` and `clientY`, and then pass that object to `create_particles()`.

So, something along the lines of this:

```
// let el = document.elementFromPoint( x, y )
// el.click()

// Create an event object, and populate clientX/clientY fields with x/y
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y
});

// Invoke create_particles with your event object
create_particles( event )
```

Alternatively, you could `dispatch` the event on the DOM element where your `click` listener is registered, to trigger it's `click` event logic by doing this:

```
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y
});

// Cause the 'click' event to be invoked on the square DOM element
square.dispatchEvent(event);
```